# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=2.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5.2

I installed the 4.5.2 framework onto my R2 dev server last week, and have been getting this error, ever since.  The files contain no reference to VisualStudio.Shell.  Any ideas?

> Parser Error  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File: /App_WebReferences/ClientApplicationServer/    Line: 1
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   could not be loaded.

Comment: do you have the dll in the bin folder of that project?

Comment: There is a bin folder, and the dll is not in it.

Comment: The original author his been shot, and his head left as an example to all that follow.  [sigh]  If only.

Comment: @Joe: Just remove the reference and remove the code, if any, that is being called (I highly doubt there will be any).

Comment: it may be due to dependency on aforesaid Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell internally(or dependency of dependencies) on Framework (hence no direct references)

Comment: To whom trying to install shell for SSMS extensions, this github issue provides a valid assemblybinding redirect solution: [link](https://github.com/TaoK/PoorMansTSqlFormatter/issues/234)

Answer (score 1):

So I spent about 2 days trying to figure out what the heck was going...

The way I was able to fix it is by adding Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell to
C:\Windows\assembly

But the only way to do that is using [gacutil](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.dll
```

That fixed it for me. Hopefully it helps someone with the same problem.

Comment: If the path variable is not set the above command will not find them. You must be in the `\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies` directory or copy the files locally to run that command. I had to register a bunch of other dlls to get my regasm command to work.

Comment: it doesn't appear in my c:/windows/assembly folder